# To create a a condition keep prompting user to reinput answer to a query

Tags: python

I want to create a condition that keeps letting user to provide the input to a questions until a non duplicate answer is give. I have updated the code but then it doesn't work, therefore I am looking for help. The code is as below:

My original code:

```
choice=int(input("Enter your move (1-9):".strip()))-1
if board[choice] ==" ":
    board[choice] = icon
else:
    print()
    print("That space is taken!")
```

The problem of the code is this does not give the user the chance to re input the answer again if duplicate chocie was entered. I changed the code into below:

Updated code

```
def check_duplicate():
    while board[choice] !=" ":
        print ("Duplicate input")
        choice=int(input("Enter your move (1-9):".strip()))-1
        board[choice]
```

I used check_duplicate to replace the old code above. It does not work. Can somebody please point out what error I have committed? Thanks.

Comment: What does "duplicated input" mean? Duplicated how?

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `choice` and `board` to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input code into a loop. Here is one way to do that:

```
while True:
    choice=int(input("Enter your move (1-9):".strip()))-1
    if board[choice] ==" ":
        board[choice] = icon
        break
    else:
        print()
        print("That space is taken!")
```

There are other ways, but this method of using `while True:` and stopping with a `break` statement is common in Python.

Note that this loop will never stop if there are no open spots on the board or if the user refused to enter an open spot for some reason. Make sure you prevent the former from happening.

---

As for the particular problems with your updated code:

1. You print "Duplicate input" before any input is taken.
2. After the input is taken, you execute `board[choice]` which only evaluates the board position... and then throws it away without doing anything.

The apparent problems with your original code:

1. It does not give the user the chance to re input the answer again if duplicate chocie was entered (as you noted).
2. If a number was inputted, the code assumes the space was taken without actually checking to see if this was the case.

I can't tell you just what your correct code should be, because you do not give enough context to understand just what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However what is wrong with my code?    

My understanding of my updated code:
1) When choice is not empty, print duplicate
2) Enter choice again
3) Update choice. Since board[choice] is no longer empty, break loop.

Instead the result I got is the loop is not breaking.